# If s∧t |= ¬t and s∧¬t |= ¬t then s |= ¬t.

Tags: logic

Im struggling with the following problem in propositional logic:

"is it true that

If $s\land t \vDash \lnot t$ and $s\land \lnot t \vDash \lnot t$ then $s \vDash \lnot t$."

where $s\vDash t$ means $s$ logically implies $t$ - "whenever s is true t is true".

using the assumptions any valuation that makes $t$ true makes not $t$ true, does this imply that $\lnot t$ is a tautology?

What seems a very simple problem has had me staring at it for ages now and would be grateful for some help

Answer (score 1):

The first premise implies $\lnot (s\land t)$ because otherwise we get a contradiction. But this means $s\implies \lnot t$ because if I tell you $s$ is true, then if $t$ were also true we would have $s\land t$ which we showed cannot be the case. So $s\implies \lnot t$  The second premise is tautological.

Answer (score 0):

A model for propositional logic is simply a *valuation* that assigns True or False to each propositional letter.

A formula is a tautology if it evaluates to True in every model (i.e., under *every* valuation). Certainly, $\lnot t$ is not a tautology for propositional letter $p$.

Now, take any model (valuation) $\eta$ where $s$ is True. We want either to prove that $\lnot t$ is True as well, or to find a counterexample model.

Now $t$ is evaluated to either True or False in this particular model $\eta$. In both cases, one of the hypotheses implies $\lnot t$.